# Custom REST Webservice in Managed Package

Tags: rest-api, managed-package

I want to change @RestResource(urlMapping='/xyz/*') value of webservice class which is a part of released Managed package. Whenever I try to edit the url of class I get internal salesforce error. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the (not so graceful) error because it is not possible to change the URL of a REST resource class in a managed package which has been released.

Unfortunately you will need to move your functionality to a new Apex class and implement the new REST URL there.

I can't find where it is documented but this is what I was told by SFDC support when I tried to do the same ~6 months ago.

Comment: Please mark as answered if I've answered your question, thanks.

Comment: And the class is not deletable from managed package since it has global access?

Comment: Correct, it's can't be deleted as it's defined as global.